# For loop using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the correct way to using "for" loop in jquery function? TQ in advance.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 for(var $i=1; $i<=10; $i++){
     $('#TTID[$i]').change(function() {
         if($(this).val() == "601" || $(this).val() == "9999")
         {
             $('#trainGroup[$i]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#trainID[$i]').prop('disabled', true);
         }
         else
         {
             $('#trainGroup[$i]').prop('disabled', false);
     $('#trainID[$i]').prop('disabled', false);
         }
     }});
 
 });
</script>
```

This is the HTML code for TTID and trainGroup. When user choose value "601" or "9990", dropdown list for trainGroup will be disable.

```html
<td>Action</td>
  <td><select name = "TTID<?php echo $i; ?>" id="TTID<?php echo $i; ?>" style="width:250px" onchange="otherAction(this.value)">
  <option value="O"></option>
     <option value="600">Classroom Training</option>
    <option value="601">Coaches and Mentoring by IM</option>
    <option value="602">On Job Training</option>
  <option value="9999">Others</option>
  </select></td>
  
 
  <td>Types Training in ILSAS</td>
  <td><select name = "trainGroup<?php echo $i; ?>" id="trainGroup<?php echo $i; ?>" style="width:250px" onchange="otherIlsas(this.value)">
  <option value="O"></option>
     <option value="700">Power Engineering & Energy Training</option>
    <option value="701">Management Training</option>
    <option value="702">IT & Corporate System Training</option>
  <option value="703">Business Operation Tools Certification</option>
  <option value="9999">Others</option>
  </select></td>
```

Below is trainID code. I retrieved the data from the database for this dropdown list.

```html
  <td>List of Training in ILSAS</td>
  <td><?php 
  
  $u="SELECT trainID, trainText FROM tbltraininglist order by traintext asc";
  $q=mysql_query($u);
  
  echo "<select name = 'trainID<?php echo $i; ?>' id='trainID<?php echo $i; ?>' style='width:250px' )'>";
  echo "<option value ='null'></option>";
  while ($m = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
  
    
    ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $m['trainID'];  ?>"><?php echo $m['trainText']; ?> </option>
   <?php
    } 
  
  ?>
  </select></td>
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML for `#TTID`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your for loop with all the problems fixed

Explanation of your errors follows the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        (function(TTID, trainGroup, trainID) {
            $(TTID).change(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == "601" || $(this).val() == "9999") {
                    $(trainGroup).prop('disabled', true);
                    $(trainID).prop('disabled', true);
                } else {
                    $(trainGroup).prop('disabled', false);
                    $(trainID).prop('disabled', false);
                }
            });
        }('#TTID[' + $i + ']', '#trainGroup[' + $i + ']', '#trainID[' + $i + ']'));
    }
});
```

1) you had things like `$('#TTID[$i]')` - where $i was the var in the for loop - that wont work in javascript, you would've needed `$('#TTID[' + $i + ']')` - however,

2) $i would be 11 for **every** .change function because that's it's value once the loop is done and the .change would only get called after the loop is finished, so, I wrapped the .change stuff in an IIEF, and fixed up the $i issue your code would've had in the one go

Comment: I'm sorry. I accidentally erased the original post when i want to edit the question. I have try your answer but it's not work.

Comment: well, I don't see any trainID's in your html - you get any errors in the console?

Comment: I have add trainID HTML code. there is no error when run but the dropdown list is not function like disable trainGroup when I choose value "601" or "9999"